# camera2 size surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2

I am developing an Android app that must show camera inside LinearLayout. I am creating a Fragment with a SurfaceView and Camera2 object. After a lot of work I could show camera over surfaceview but I am having problems with size.

Camera's image is begin showed just in a part and the rest is just a black screen. I tried to define width and height that surfaceChanged give me with setFixedSize but I get this error

Surface with size (w=516, h=828) and format 0x4 is not valid, size not in valid set: [1440x1080, 1280x720, 960x720, 880x720, 960x540, 720x540, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 528x432, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]

If I define some of the sizes in the message I can get camera image but not over all my surface just a part and the rest is black.

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is how I get valid device sizes. I am taking first in the list but I tried with all availables sizes

```
val map = cameraCharacteristics!!.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)    

                medida= map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder::class.java)[0]
                w=medida.width
                h=medida.height
```

Then I set size with

```
override fun surfaceCreated(p0: SurfaceHolder?) {
        p0!!.setFixedSize(w,h)

        Superficie = p0!!.surface
    }
```

And this is the image I get
[image]

Comment: Add the resource code for xml

Comment: Hello The only xml I am using is the linearlayout. I am creating surfaceview with a class like this class CameraViewV2(context: Context) : SurfaceView(context), SurfaceHolder.Callback {} I am replacing linearlayout with a fragment. Is that correct? thanks

Comment: you may add the surface view in the xmlfile and customize it as you want.

Comment: It is better to be used with TextureView for more control

Comment: Ok. I will try with TextureView. Because with SurfaceView is not working. Thanks

Comment: I solved it ! I add this line in side init of my surfaceview class.       this.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))